# Is it safe & easy to travel from Israel to West Bank by taxi?

Tags: safety, taxis, israel, palestine

I am going to be in Israel for a while and was invited to a Friday-night dinner by some acquaintances that live in the West Bank. I, however, will be living in Tel Aviv.

First, is it possible to take a taxi from Israel into the West Bank, or will a change or taxis be necessary? If so, can I use something like Uber, or must I take an actual cab?

Second, I would need to get back to Tel Aviv at night after dinner. Is it possible to cross back into the rest of Israel at night? Can easily I do this via taxi/Uber, or would I need to pre-arrange it? Also, would being driven in such an area at night be generally safe? (I am Jewish traveling on an American passport)

Comment: Where exactly at the west bank are you going to, there are vast differences if you go to C area, which is Israeli controlled area, or A and B areas which are PA territories? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Bank_Areas_in_the_Oslo_II_Accord)

Comment: Would you visit an illegal Israeli settlement or an occupied Palestinian settlement?

Comment: @gerrit no need for the language of illegal....they are disputed settlements.

Comment: @andrewmh20 The settlements have been repeatedly declared illegal by the UN, by the Israeli Supreme Court, and by various non-UN representatives of the international community many times.  I'm aware the Israeli government disputes this, so *disputed* is technically correct.  However, I feel no need to give undue weight to the minority opinion of the Israeli government, in particular since I'm not writing an “NPOV” Wikipedia article but a personal comment in my name.  Therefore, I fully stand by my choice of word *illegal*.

Comment: @gerrit it's a common courtesy on Travel.SE to avoid dragging politics into answers/comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crossing into the West Bank itself is simply a matter of continuing on whatever road you were already on and passing a check point, (though usually they are only checking  anyone going the other way) and it's perfectly doable with an Israeli taxi, or any one else willing to take you there for that matter.

Furthermore, it's just as doable to procede from there into an Israeli settlement; it's just like driving into any other town.

However, I would recommend finding out the best way to get there in advance from the person who lives there, as many roads can be much more safe than others.

It is also perfectly possible to return to the fully recognized part of Israel, this time through an actual checkpoint, again in any Israeli vehicle. Whether you will have to pre -arrange depends on where you are; your host will likely know local taxi options. However, for a journey to Tel Aviv it may be a good idea to pre-book regardless.

In terms of general safety, both day and night it depends where exactly you are. But in all cases most likely people living there will say it's safe enough for them to travel. At the same time there are other places that are probably statistically safer to be, so it really is up to your comfort level. This is another question that would be best for your host who is likely familiar with the exact roads you will be on.

(Also, obviously a taxi from Tel Aviv will cost quite a bit)

Getting to Palestinian towns from the west bank will be very different, as Israeli taxis will not go there, and there may be more security checks on the way in and/or out of the towns/cities. You will have to take an Israeli car into the west bank as above and then transfer somewhere to Palestinian transportation.

Comment: The main safety issue would be rocks/shots at your car.

Comment: ...or harassment from IDF, depending on who and where you are...

Comment: I was referring to the safety concerns in the situation mentioned in the bulk of my answer, which was an Israeli vehicle. Yes if you go to Palestinian towns, as per the last paragraph, there will be additional safety issues.